# can't get the size of an array right in C

Tags: c, arrays, sizeof

The exercise I'm doing asked to create an array of 50 characters, to put it in a structure and then use a subroutine to print the array on the screen and to say how many characters it has ( there's more but the problem that I have is here )

this is what I did

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <string.h>

    int Anzahl (char []);

    int main ()

    {
    int x;
    char kette [50];
    printf ("Type down something\n");
    fgets (kette,50,stdin);

    struct hullo {
        char kette [50];
    };
    x=Anzahl (&kette[50]);
    printf ("the number of letters is : %d", x);
    }


    int Anzahl (char kette[50])
    {
    int x1;
    puts (&kette[50]);
    x1 = sizeof (kette[50]);
    return x1;
    }
```

`

but each time I type something, the number of characters is always 1 in the end.
would be nice if someone could explain to me what I did wrong.

Comment: `Anzahl (&kette[50]);`.. your compiler din;t scream?

Comment: C doesn’t know array sizes.

Answer (score 2):

You are wrong, on two fronts.

**Firstly**, the function call

```
 x=Anzahl (&kette[50]);
```

is wrong (not syntactically, from the actual usage point of view), you need to pass the starring address, just like `x=Anzahl (kette);`

**Secondly**, arrays, when passed as function arguments, delays to pointer to the first elements. So, you cannot use `sizeof` to get the expected *size* from the parameter that received the input argumet.

Quoting `C11`, chapter §6.3.2.1

> Except when it is the operand of the sizeof operator, the _Alignof operator, or the
>   unary & operator, or is a string literal used to initialize an array, an expression that has
>   type ‘‘array of type’’ is converted to an expression with type ‘‘pointer to type’’ that points
>   to the initial element of the array object and is not an lvalue.

and, chapter §6.7.6.3

> A declaration of a parameter as *‘‘array of type’’* shall be adjusted to *‘‘qualified pointer to
>   type’’*, where the type qualifiers (if any) are those specified within the `[` and `]` of the
>   array type derivation. [...]

**Bonus:**

```
  puts (&kette[50]);
```

is also wrong. It's off-by-one, as C arrays are 0-based indexed. In this case, you're passing an *invalid* pointer (and accessing the memory location therefor to read the content), you have [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Comment: The first thing is not a type error. &kette[50] is a char*, and some compilers decay array types to pointers directly. Then indexing and the pointer pointing after the array will be a problem to the Runtime.

Answer (score 0):

You can't call `sizeof array` on a function argument, since in C arrays decay to pointer. This means as soon as you call `Anzahl(&kette);` the "50" will just be discarded, and your function will look like `int Anzahl(char *);`. This is just one of your problems though, since you call `sizeof` on `kette[50]`. This will return the size of a `char` in bytes, which should always be 1. Instead you should be calling `sizeof(kette)`, but this will not work because of the reasons I mentioned earlier. This could be fixed by wrapping the array in a struct like 
`typedef struct arr { char[50]; } arr;` and then using this struct instead of `kette[50]`.

You should also be calling `Anzahl(kette)` instead of `&kette[50]`, same goes with puts.

Answer (score 0):

Sourav Ghosh is right! The final version should be:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
int Anzahl(char kette[50]);
int main (){
    int x;
    char kette[50];
    printf ("Type down something\n");
    fgets (kette,50,stdin);
    x=Anzahl(kette);
    printf ("the number of letters is : %d", x);
}


int Anzahl (char kette[50]){
    int x1;
    puts(kette);
    //this will print 8
    x1 = sizeof(kette);
    //if you need the string length you should use
    //but this will include the \n terminator...
    return strlen(kette);
}
```